# What is a basic font in swift I can use for UILabel

Tags: xcode, swift, fonts, uilabel

How can I use different system fonts for the line **//pointsLabel.font = FontHUD**, no custom font but different fonts available in the system

```
 //"points" label
    var pointsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(ScreenWidth-340, 30, 140, 70))
    pointsLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    //pointsLabel.font = FontHUD
    pointsLabel.text = " Points:"
    self.addSubview(pointsLabel)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(style: String)` and pass any of the following as the style:

```
UIFontTextStyleHeadline
UIFontTextStyleSubheadline
UIFontTextStyleBody
UIFontTextStyleFootnote
UIFontTextStyleCaption1
UIFontTextStyleCaption2
```

On a bit of a side note - an advantage of using `preferredFontForTextStyle` is that you can use it to make your app support Dynamic Type because the size of the font returned varies depending on the user's preferred text size (set in the Settings app under Display & Brightness -> Text Size). To fully support dynamic type you should listen for changes in the preferred font size using `NSNotifcationCenter` and observing `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification`, then updating your labels/textviews appropriately.